I have an error which suggests that I must update includePath otherwise the error is File.h: No such file or directory gcc
SCREENSHOT PICTURE



In folder source
The prototype in the file control.h:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

double rectangularArea (double width, double height);

The file main.c:
int main(){

    double result;
    result = rectangularArea(10.0,20.0);
    printf("The rectangle air is %f",result);

    return 0;
}

The function in file control.c:

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include  "file.h" // error here

double rectangularArea (double width, double height)
{
    return width * height;
}


You need #include "youfolder/file.h". If this isn't clear, then [edit] the question and show your folder structure and show in which folder file.c and file.h are.

BTW: where are your includes in main.c ?

Please [edit] and show the folder structure (show it and don't describe it). Otherwise it's hard to tell what's wrong.

Thanks for trying to show the folder structure, but unfortunately it's still unclear where each folder is. Show the complete folder structure including the relevant files they contain.

To show directory structure cd to your folder and use tree command or or find . | sed -e "s/[^-][^\/]*\// |/g" -e "s/|\([^ ]\)/|-\1/"  command and add its output to your post.

@GhorbanM.Tavakoly OP is on Windows., so only tree will work.

#include "Headers/controller.h" -> #include "../Headers/controller.h". Otherwise the compiler will look for controller.h in "source/Headers/".

Not related to the error, but you should urgently learn how to create screenshots on your PC. For most error messages just copy&paste the messages as text into the question. If you need to show some window content, use your OS mechanism to provide screenshots. Using smartphone to take a photo, close to always results in low quality pictures. For Windows, you can use Win+Shift+s to get to the snipping tool.

Try adding ${workspaceFolder}/Headers to the includePath array in the c_cpp_properties.json file.

You will saw the error in main.c file screenshot and i try with  #include "../Headers/controller.h"
